# How to setup Hive and Hadoop on Windows 10?

Tags: hadoop, hive, windows-10

I recently installed Hadoop and hive on my windows 10 Pro and facing an issue when starting hive 3.1.2:
JPS command shows everything including Derby is up and running and despite changing guava jar file (as suggested by some websites) by using the Hadoop version rather than the one delivered by hive, I still got the following issue (old=guava-19.0 new=guava-27.0-jre)

**Any pointing in the right direction will be more than appreciated**

### Jps :

10160 NameNode
11904 NetworkServerControl
13328 ResourceManager
4496 NodeManager
12708 DataNode
11596 Jps

### error

```
hive
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.<br>
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/zztop/Hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]<br>
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/zztop/Hive/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]<br>
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/zztop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]<br>
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.<br>
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]<br>
2020-06-19T23:10:49,762 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - Found configuration file file:/C:/zztop/Hive/conf/hive-site.xml<br>
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)'<br>

        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1357)<br>
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1338)<br>
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.setJar(JobConf.java:518)<br>
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.setJarByClass(JobConf.java:536)<br>
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.<init>(JobConf.java:430)<br>
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.initialize(HiveConf.java:5141)<br>
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.<init>(HiveConf.java:5099)<br>
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4jCommon(LogUtils.java:97)<br>
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4j(LogUtils.java:81)<br>
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:699)<br>
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)<br>
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)<br>
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)<br>
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)<br>
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)<br>
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:318)<br>
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:232)<br>
```

*here are the details of the versions*

## hadoop version

> java version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode,
> sharing)
> Hadoop 3.1.3
> This command was run using
> /C:/zztop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.1.3.jar
> hive 3.1.2 Windows 10 Pro - i5 intel Cpu

Comment: 1) Hadoop does not support JDK 14(see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP/Hadoop+Java+Versions)
2) Hive/Hadoop won't run natively on Windows, you have to setup comparability layer in order to run them (see https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils)
3) Your particular problem indicates that you have a wrong version of `guava` in your CLASSPATH

Comment: Here are my question/comments after trying to fix it myself - First and foremost : what does it mean "guava version is wrong in my classpath"? I did replace with the guava that come with hadoop but still facing an issue ... is there a matrix somewhere saying " if you use this version of hadoop and that of hive then use this" //// for the rest (and in order to help other beginer) hadoop is working perfectly with my JDK and the winutils propose will not work with the version of hadoop I am running - beginer should be carfull of using the verstion that match the hadoop version

Comment: Do not replace JAR files. That'll just make it worse

Comment: It did! What would be your recommendation to troubleshooting this issue?